# Firebug Error: setInterval() Callbacks Cease after Continue from Breakpoint

Tags: javascript, firebug, setinterval

I stumbled upon a show-stopper glitch in Firebug wherein if a breakpoint is hit in a JavaScript callback method, and execution is subsequently continued [F8], any callback functions previously passed to setTimeout() or setInterval() will no longer be called.

This bug was reported to whomever handles Firebug development back in March of 2010. You can read the official case here:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2894

I'm assuming that since the problem still hasn't been fixed after a year, it likely never will be fixed. So my question is this: Do you know of any clever workarounds for this Firebug glitch? Is there some convoluted way to get the timer events to fire again aside from restarting Firefox and/or reloading the page?

UPDATE:

To clarify: In order to trigger the glitch, the breakpoint must be located on ANY line, on ANY event callback, ANYWHERE in the program, EXCEPT FOR in the setInterval()/setTimeout() callback itself.

Comment: The bug-page that you link to doesn't mention `setTimeout`; if you're certain that `setTimeout` is affected, I think you should post a comment there to that effect. Also, I don't think it's reasonable to assume "that since the problem still hasn't been fixed after a year, it likely never will be fixed" (though obviously a workaound can be useful in the interim).

Comment: Hi. The bug page presents a very specific case regarding animation and handling clicks. Whoever submitted that bug report probably didn't realize that the bug can be generalized to ALL setInterval()/setTimeout calls, not just those involving animation. I respectfully disagree on the second point. If a major show-stopping bug hasn't been fixed (or even addressed!) after a year, it likely won't get fixed. It's not that anyone's being negligent; It's probably just too hard to fix it a reasonable time frame. Thanks for the response.

Comment: ruakh is right. Even when that bug isn't fixed yet, it doesn't mean it will never be fixed. Firebug is currently moving towards a [new debugger API](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421), which will allow to address this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug 1.12.6 fixes issue [1830](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1830) (duplicate of the [2894](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2894))

https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/01/20/firebug-1-12-6/

All running timeouts (and intervals) are now paused when Firebug's debugger is paused. You can check this behavior using an online test case (and Firebug 1.12.6) here:

https://getfirebug.com/tests/manual/issues/1830/firebug-async-breakpoint.htm

Honza